# ¿Como ver imagen en pantalla completa al dar click sobre ella?

Tags: android

Buen día.

Tengo una imagen en mi layout, al dar click sobre ella debería mostrarse en pantalla completa ¿Como podría hacerlo?. De antemano gracias.

aqui el activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgShow);

    Picasso.with(this).load("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/19/Optimus10108pieces.jpg").into(image);

}
```

aqui el xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgShow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_upload"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp" />
```

Comment: comparte tu código, añade el xml y el evento en java en donde se hace click(tap) sobre la imagen.

Comment: ¿qué es es lo que envuelva al imageView? ¿un relative layout?

Comment: si, correcto  @Rene Limon

Comment: considera añadir eso tambien.

Answer (score 3):

Se podria hacer de esta forma:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_tu_imagen"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ActivityUpload.java**

```
public class ActivityUpload extends Activity {

    ImageView imageView;

    boolean isImageFitToScreen;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgShow);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isImageFitToScreen) {
                    isImageFitToScreen=false;
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                }else{
                    isImageFitToScreen=true;
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta Rene Limon, hay alguna manera de hacer que la imagen apareciera en una especie de popup?

Comment: ¬¬ eso cambia totalmente el sentido de la pregunta.

Comment: @ReneLimon  si no estas seguro de lo que quieres, te recomiendo bajarte la apk "Librerías para desarroladores", en ella hay varias librerias que hacen lo que quieres y en base a eso, podrías reformular tu pregunta, que de momento ya e respondió.